# What is the fastest way to copy a large number of file paths mentioned in a text file, from one directory to another

Tags: unix, parallel-processing, cp

I have a text file that lists a large number of file paths. I need to copy all these files from the source directory (mentioned in the path in the file one every line) to a destination directory.

Currently, the command line I tried is

```
while read line; do cp $ line dest_dir; done < my_file.txt
```

This seems to be a bit slow. Is there a way to parallelise this whole thing or speed it up ?

Comment: *Is there a way to parallelise this whole thing*  Do you have a disk system capable of simultaneous reads and writes to and from multiple locations ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I am on a unix server and it is connected to an external SSD disk.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark so I have a file containing a large set of file paths of files that are on the SSD. I need to copy them into a directory on the server. Even though the SSD is mounted on the machine, the objective is to copy it to server and then do scp command to copy the whole directory to my laptop.

Comment: It sounds to me as if you have a single 'pipe' from SSD to laptop so any attempts at parallelisation are likely to be nugatory.

Answer (score 2):

You could try **GNU Parallel** as follows:

```
parallel --dry-run -a fileList.txt cp {} destinationDirectory
```

If you like what it says, remove the `--dry-run`.

Comment: Parallelizing disk i/o may or may not be faster: https://oletange.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/parallel-disk-io-is-it-faster/

Comment: @OleTange Yes, thank you. I was aware of that, and I was trying to imply it was just a suggestion to try out - like you say in your article. The link to your article is very appropriate - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something **like** the following (in your chosen shell)

```
    #!/bin/bash

    BATCHSIZE=2

    # **NOTE**: check exists with -f and points at the right place. you might not need this. depends on your own taste for risk.
    ln -s `which cp` /tmp/myuniquecpname 

    # **NOTE**: this sort of thing can have limits in some shells
    for i in `cat test.txt`  
    do 

    BASENAME="`basename $i`"

    echo doing /tmp/myuniquecpname $i test2/$BASENAME & 

    /tmp/myuniquecpname $i test2/$BASENAME & 

    COUNT=`ps -ef | grep /tmp/myuniquecpname | grep -v grep | wc -l`

    # **NOTE**: maybe need to put a timeout on this loop
    until [ $COUNT -lt $BATCHSIZE ]; do

    COUNT=`ps -ef | grep /tmp/myuniquecpname | grep -v grep | wc -l`
    echo waiting...
    sleep 1

    done

    done
```